# Are questions pertaining to high school relevant here?

Tags: discussion

There do seem to be a couple of questions regarding HS things on this site and as an Indian HS student I just wanted to clarify this before posting questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that questions pertaining to high school are off topic here, but questions about being a student or doing research or getting admitted to a academic program can be very much on topic. The thing you need to ask yourself, and it is difficult from the perspective of a high school student, is is my question applicable to graduate students, either current or perspective.

It might help if you ask a meta question with some of your potential questions and people can maybe give you some pointers of how to make them more on topic.

Comment: This is exactly right. Questions related to admissions exams, specific coursework, etc., are off-topic; however, anything related to _how to do research_ would be very much on-topic.